# What exactly does the gc.collect() function do?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I am having trouble understanding what exactly the python function `gc.collect()` does.
Does the function only collects those objects that are collectable, to free up the space at a later time once the `gc.threshold` is reached? or does `gc.collect()` collect objects and also automatically get rid of whatever it collected, so that the space can be freed immediately after executing the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends! If called with no argument or with `generation=2` as an argument, it would free the objects that are collectable. If called with `generation=1` it would not clear the free lists.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect):

> With no arguments, run a full collection. The optional argument generation may be an integer specifying which generation to collect (from 0 to 2). A `ValueError` is raised if the generation number is invalid. The number of unreachable objects found is returned.
>
> The free lists maintained for a number of built-in types are cleared whenever a full collection or collection of the highest generation (2) is run. Not all items in some free lists may be freed due to the particular implementation, in particular float.